# Remove blank lines in txt output from R

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to create a specifically formatted file to use as an input file in another software. I have been able, with the help of people here, to create a file that is almost there. Now I just need to remove some empty lines in my *.txt output file. I have tried several different approaches with gsub() but can't figure out a way. Below is an example that produces a file that shows where I'm stuck.

```
matsplitter<-function(M, r, c) {
rg <- (row(M)-1)%/%r+1
cg <- (col(M)-1)%/%c+1
rci <- (rg-1)*max(cg) + cg
N <- prod(dim(M))/r/c
cv <- unlist(lapply(1:N, function(x) M[rci==x]))
dim(cv)<-c(r,c,N)
cv}

B <- matrix(c(1:1380),ncol=5)
capture.output(matsplitter(B,3,5), file='output.txt')
write.table(gsub('\\[.*\\]', '', 
readLines('output.txt')), 
file='output.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

What I need to further remove are the two blank lines between the ", , 1", ", , 2" etc. string and the matrix of numbers.

```
    x
    , , 1


        1  277  553 829 1105
        2  278  554  830 1106
        3  279  555  831 1107

    , , 2


        4  280  556  832 1108
        5  281  557  833 1109
        6  282  558  834 1110

    , , 3


        7  283  559  835 1111
        8  284  560  836 1112
        9  285  561  837 1113
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution if you are willing to go beyond `gsub`. I have taken the liberty of breaking the answer up into pieces for clarity (hopefully).

```
#read in file created by "capture.out"
out = gsub('\\[.*\\]', '', readLines('output.txt'))
```

If you look at this object `out` you will see that blocks seem separated by five spaces, and that the first of the two spaces you want to get rid of is an empty string `""`. We get rid of the multiple spaces by means of:

```
out = gsub("\\s{5}","",out)
```

Now after the header but in front of every block there is two empty strings and after every block there is one empty string. As we only look to exclude spaces in front of blocks we use the function `rle` to find repeating elements and exclude these.

```
#get indicator vector
exclvec = rep(rle(out)$lengths,rle(out)$lengths)

#remove values as indicated by exclvec
out = out[ifelse(out=="" & exclvec==2,F,T)]
```

As i interpret your question writing this dataframe provides the desired result.

```
write.table(out,file='output.txt', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed and thank you for the thorough explanation!